# File API is causing ANR's

Tags: java, android, file, android-asynctask

A small part of my application checks if files exist on the user's device. The list of files is potentially quite long - apparently long enough to cause ANR's with a few users. A thousand files is by no means impossible.

The code is quite simple:

```
new File(fileUrl).exists()
```

I'm currently doing it on the main thread, as I need the operations to be blocking. I could do it using an `AsyncTask` class and then continue the rest of the work once it's done, but I'm wondering if that's a valid cause?

All the work is being done in a background `Service`, if that changes anything. I'm also potentially going to experience orientation changes, and that might be annoying with `AsyncTask`. Would a `Handler` be better?

So, to sum things up: Should I do use an AsyncTask for a potentially long-running operation in a background Service, where orientation changes may occur?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a `Service` isn't affected by orientation change - it's only the currently running `Activity` class which is destroyed / recreated.

Secondly, an `AsyncTask` isn't of much advantage in a `Service` as it's designed to be able to interact with the UI. It would give the advantage of doing work on a separate thread but the rest of the methods would basically be redundant.

I'd recommend using an `IntentService` which manages its own worker thread to do work. See the [IntentService documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up a lot of stuff. I was a bit confused as to whether AsyncTasks would be cancelled when running in a Service on rotation change, but that's great. I'll have a look at the IntentService class. Upvote for now!

Comment: IntentServices are awesome! I'm so sad I didn't know about them until now :(

Comment: @MichellBak : **"IntentServices are awesome!"** Yep, one of my favourite Android classes. I feel your pain - it took me months before I discovered `IntentService` just by accident when reading posts here on SO. My current app uses an `IntentService` triggered by a daily `AlarmManager` alarm to download data in the middle of the night when the user is asleep - powerful stuff. Enjoy! :D